# Change Colorbar limit for changing scale with matplotlib 3.3+

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

The code at the bottom does exactly what I want it to do, but exclusively to a `matplotlib` version below at least 3.3.4 . For this version, 3.3.4, I get the following error message:

```py
AttributeError: 'ColorBar' object has no attribute 'set_clim'
```

Accordingly, I tried to find out, how to do this in today's version, but failed.
So, how can I change the color scale of the image and the Colobar in the newer versions?

Working Code (tested in 2.2.2):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.cos(x)
y = y.reshape(10,10)

plt.ion()

figure = plt.figure()
line1 = plt.imshow(y)
cbar = plt.colorbar(line1)

for p in range(100):
    updated_y = np.random.randint(0,10)*np.cos(x-0.05*p).reshape(10,10)
    
    line1.set_data(updated_y)

    cbar.set_clim(vmin=np.min(updated_y),vmax=np.max(updated_y)) #this line creates the error
    cbar.draw_all()
    
    figure.canvas.draw()
    figure.canvas.flush_events()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution with the by @Trenton McKinneys  provided link in the following post:  [Question by Merk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59055637/changing-the-colorbar-limits-in-a-mpl-toolkits-mplot3d-plot).

Solved code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.cos(x)
y = y.reshape(10,10)

plt.ion()

figure = plt.figure()
line1 = plt.imshow(y)
cbar = plt.colorbar(line1)

for p in range(100):
    updated_y = np.random.randint(0,10)*np.cos(x-0.05*p).reshape(10,10)
    
    line1.set_data(updated_y)

    #cbar.set_clim(vmin=np.min(updated_y),vmax=np.max(updated_y)) #this line creates the error
    cbar.mappable.set_clim(vmin=np.min(updated_y),vmax=np.max(updated_y)) #this works
    cbar.draw_all()
    
    figure.canvas.draw()
    figure.canvas.flush_events()
    time.sleep(1)
```

(One) provided image:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

- See [matplotlib: api_changes_3.1.0/ColorbarBase inheritance](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/api_changes.html#colorbarbase-inheritance)
- Per [matplotlib: api_changes_3.3.0/removals.rst](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/a8831d57207db5e9bf681e30810ce0ea146f4a31/doc/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.3.0/removals.rst):

  - Using `colorbar.ColorbarBase.set_clim` results in `AttributeError: 'ColorBar' object has no attribute 'set_clim'`
  - Use `matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable.set_clim` instead
- See [`matplotlib.cm`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cm_api.html), [`matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable), [`set_clim()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable.set_clim), and [`matplotlib.colorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/colorbar_api.html)

---

- Also, `.set_clim` can be used on a returned image object, instead of the colorbar object.
- [matplotlib: Image Tutorial Example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/images.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-images-py) modified to use object oriented interface.

  - Using [stinkbug.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwJwG.png)

```py
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = mpimg.imread('stinkbug.png')
lum_img = img[:, :, 0]

fig, (ax1, ax2)= plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 7))

im1 = ax1.imshow(lum_img)
im1.set_cmap('nipy_spectral')
ax1.set_title('Before')
fig.colorbar(im1, ax=ax1, ticks=[0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7], orientation='horizontal')

im2 = ax2.imshow(lum_img)
im2.set_cmap('nipy_spectral')
im2.set_clim(0.0, 0.7)  # set clim on the im2 image object
ax2.set_title('After')
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2, ticks=[0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7], orientation='horizontal')
```

[image]